# executeFetchRequest:error: is consuming a lot of time

Tags: ios, core-data

I profiled my app against the time profile template, and just noticed that the processing performed by `executeFetchRequest:error:` is consuming a huge amount of time since it's done multiple times and towards a lot of record in coredata.

```
-(Customer *) getCustomerByName:(NSString *)_name

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@",_name];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchReq setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchReq setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"customer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];  
    NSArray *all = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil];
if ([all count] > 0) {
       return (Customer*)[all objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return nil;
```

}

The call of the method above is done more than once, I can confirm it's doing the call around 2000 times. So each time, the `executeFetchRequest:error:` is fetching a huge number of records in coredata to check whether the customer does exist. Is there anyway to change the processing of `executeFetchRequest:error:` in order to reduce time consumed? any thoughts?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it help if you set fetchLimit to 1, it seems you only want the first result.

```
[fetchReq setFetchLimit:1];
```

Comment: Ok, will check that and profile the app again against this change. Thanx for your reply.

Comment: Yep, that drop it from `40%` to `0.3%`. Thanx.